# Content Builder Approvals erroring

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I have a user that I have added them to a Team in Approvals. I've check the permissions and they have Allow for Approvals Comments and Approval Items.

But when I create an email I get the following error: "Error: Unable to submit for approval. Please contact your account administrator or try again." Why is the User not allow to Submit for Approval?

What permissions besides the Workflow Approvals above are needed?

Comment: I'm wondering if you ever resolved this issue. I am getting the same exact error message for a few of my users and all permissions appear to be accurate.

Comment: We did resolve the issue, unfortunately the specifics were a little muddy. Basically the User was lacking permissions. We had the User as a Content Creator and this did not have permissions for Subscriber. Unfortunately we were able to get the error to go away but in my haste I didn't track what permission exactly was missing. We basically added all Subscriber permissions.